# Convert mysqli_stmt::get_result() to bind_result()

Tags: php, mysql, methods, mysqli

I am trying to install mysqlnd drivers to my server, but my server is on cloud hosting site. And don't know how to enable mysqlnd server.
So i am trying another approach, of making it compatible with current php version.

How can i convert this get_result method to bind_result.

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();  // m trying to make it bind_result
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what fields are fetched from `users`, i.e. can you replace `*` by the actual field identifiers?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you want to bind_result you need to know what the column names are called in the result of your query, unless you want to write a lot of complicated code to work those fieldnames out dynamically. Is that what you have been asked to do?

Comment: $name, $email, $password are fetched from users.

Comment: Well then re-write the code after the execute to bind variables to those column names. [The manual, in many languages](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)